# Is there a SciPy method to autocrop an image, i. e. trim zeros from a 2d `numpy.ndarray`?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, crop, trim

For 1d `numpy.ndarray` there is [`numpy.trim_zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html). Which method from `numpy` or `scipy` can I use to trim zeros for 2d arrays?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0], [0, 3, 6, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 6, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The result I'd like to get:

```
array([[4, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 6]])
```

Comment: What if the second column were all zeros?

Comment: `a=np.transpose(a[np.sum(a,1)==0])` twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would search for position of leftmost, rightmost, topmost and bottommost nonzeros and then slice that array following way:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0], [0, 3, 6, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
nzero = np.nonzero(a)
top,bottom = np.min(nzero[0]),np.max(nzero[1])
left,right = np.min(nzero[1]),np.max(nzero[1])
out = a[top:bottom+1,left:right+1] # +1 as second argument is exclusive
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[4 1 2]
 [0 3 6]]
```

Note that this method might be easily adopted also to 3D arrays by adding `nearest` and `farthest`, which would be respectively `np.min` and `np.max` of `nzero[2]`

Answer (score 2):

You can try a list comprehension with some `numpy` methods:

```
>>> np.array([sub[~(sub == 0)].tolist() for sub in a if sub[sub != 0].tolist()])
array([[4, 1, 2], [3, 6]], dtype=object)
>>>
```